# Where is the certificate choice for a Windows VPN connection stored?

Tags: windows, vpn, connection, certificate

Is it possible to find out which certificate was used to set up a VPN connection configured for certificate authentication? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance

Note: We've looked for this in the phonebook, in the connection properties returned by Get-VpnConnection (Powershell) including the EAP settings. We've also looked in the registry for the certificate's thumbprint, serial and subject (name), just in case, but found nothing.